# Pass UIImage from one class to another

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, avfoundation

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297) for capturing images with AVFoundation. I'm trying to get the captured image from CaptureSessionManager (an NSObject class) back to the AROverlayViewController. How do I go about doing this?

I tried putting `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *finalImage;` in AROverlayViewController.h, then setting `arController.finalImage = image;` in CaptureSessionManager.m, but the log is saying that finalImage is `null`.

Any thoughts on how best to do this? Thanks!

Comment: how are you setting `arController` ???

Comment: I put `AROverlayViewController *arController = [[AROverlayViewController alloc] init];` in `- (void)captureStillImage` in CaptureSessionManager.m.

Comment: This is wrong here you are creating a new controller and you might be accessing the image of old controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property on the class **CaptureManager**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *stillImage;
```

which you can get by this code

```
UIImage *final = [captureManager stillImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it - add `UIImage *test = [captureManager stillImage];` in AROverlayViewController.m. God, that took me forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *imageData;

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showLoading) withObject:nil];

        UIImage *capturedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
       imageData = [[NSData alloc]init]; 
       imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturedImage);
       [imageData retain];

       [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

}
```

You can pass this NSData to other view you can acces this image.

Comment: This is using AVFoundation, not UIImagePickerController.